# Cannot import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga' in my create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, create-react-app, redux-saga

I have the following import in my create-react-app:

```
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
```

Problem is that my system is unable to import createSagaMiddleware.

I am running versions:
node 12.13.0
npm 6.12.1

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^7.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "npm": "^6.12.1",
    "react": "^16.10.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.2",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

My IDE says (Intellij IDEA) says that it 'cannot resolve symbol 'createSagaMiddleware'. 
The actual error message that I see is

```
Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions
```

which is thrown at

```
componentDidMount() {
    const {fetchCollectionsStart} = this.props;
    fetchCollectionsStart();
};
```

->

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    fetchCollectionsStart: () => dispatch(fetchCollectionsStart())
});

export default connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(ShopPage);
```

The fetchCollectionsStart action looks like this:

```
import {takeEvery} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import ShopActionTypes from "./shop.types";

export function* fetchCollectionsAsync() {
    yield console.log('I am fired');
}

export function* fetchCollectionsStart() {
    yield takeEvery(
        ShopActionTypes.FETCH_COLLECTIONS_START,
        fetchCollectionsAsync
    );
}
```

My redux store looks like this:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import {fetchCollectionsStart} from "./shop/shop.sagas";

import rootReducer from './root-reducer';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    middlewares.push(logger);
}

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));

sagaMiddleware.run(fetchCollectionsStart);

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export default { store, persistStore };
```

I have seen a similar question be asked at https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1967. 
However that answer doesn't solve it here.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you include some more info like the error you're seeing and your `package.json` contents?

Comment: Sure. I have updated the question.

Comment: Provide `fetchCollectionsStart` action

Comment: Updated the question to provide what hope you meant

Comment: Your question title is misleading.  You **are** able to import it, you are just feeding it incorrectly formed data.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm able to import it. 
If I make this modification:
    import createSagaMiddlewareFoo from 'redux-saga'; 
and 
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddlewareFoo();

The error is the same

Comment: You're probably right. I guess I am actually able to import it as whatever name since it is an 'export default'. I am new to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, actions have to be plain objects. Apparently you are dispatching a saga instead of an action.

Replace your `mapDispatchToProps` code block with:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    fetchCollectionsStart: () => {
       dispatch({ type: ShopActionTypes.FETCH_COLLECTIONS_START });
    },
});
```

Comment: Well that works! They're doing this differently (i.e. as shown in the question) in a react course that I am taking. But it seems that redux-saga has been updated since then. Thanks alot!